# Blurred images with css transformation in mobile Safari

Tags: html, css, transform, mobile-safari

there!

I have a trouble with images with css transformation in mobile Safari.
I reduce my case to this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=0.55, maximum-scale=0.55, minimum-scale=0.55, width=device-width">

    <style>
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .img {
            width: 64px;
            height: 64px;
            background-image: url(http://sa-timetobehero-2reallife.netdna-ssl.com/ds1/items/potions/1_winter_event_shield_60_60.jpg);
            background-size: 64px;
        }
        .img_transform {
            transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img img_transform"></div>
</body>
```

Result:

[image]

In mobile Safari second image looks blurred. I found that **backface-visibility** property should fix this issue, but I didnt get some effect then add it.

Comment: If you're using an iPhone with retina display, i'm pretty sure standard images may look blury. Take a look at http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/a-guide-for-creating-a-better-retina-web

Comment: man, its not my case. Images already prepared for retina displays.